# How to keep CakePHP 3 project up to date?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Starting a new project in **CakePHP 3.x**, but I want to keep the project updated with CakePHP 3. How can I keep my project's CakePHP version up to date with the latest release and changes? I don't want to check manually which files are updated and copy that files only, or copy all the CakePHP and other vendor files in my project each time anything updated. Searched on Google for hour but didn't found anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, in your terminal / console change directory to your application folder and run

```
cd mywebsite
composer update
```

read from [cakephp books](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/search.html?q=composer&check_keywords=yes&area=default)

Answer (score 1):

If you installed cakephp by composer then,
See in  `composer.json` file in your project folder.

Add

```
"require": {
        "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.0",
 }
```

If it's already added then in same direction run your composer. For that press in shift key + mouse right click then choice `use composer here`. Now you need a command

```
composer update
```

Comment: In this case, how can we keep the app skeleton up to date? If something changes in the webroot dir, for example? composer udpdate only updates the vendor directory right?